# JavaFx new Thread with same Task as input

Tags: java, json, multithreading, javafx, task

I am working on a JavaFX desktop application and I have one button that should read from the memory of an embedded device and print that into a JSON. I have implemented a Task that does that, and this Task is passed as argument to a new thread in the button event handler. The problem is, this only works once. After that, even though new threads are generated on button click, the call() method of the Task is never called again. Here is the code:

The Task definition:

```
Task readValDaemon = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        //This functions reads from memory and writes the JSON
        readDataHI(connection,commandListHI,statusHI);
        return null;
    }
};
```

The Thread creation:

```
readData.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

        Thread readValThread = new Thread(readValDaemon);
        readValThread.setDaemon(true);
        readValThread.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't span new threads every time the mouse is clicked. What does the readDataHI method does? Has it completed on the first thread spanned by the mouse event handler?

Comment: The only reason I spawn a thread on mouse click is because the reading process from the embedded NVRAM (couple of loops, 10000-ish values, writes them to JSON) takes a couple of seconds, and that would freeze the entire GUI. The thread should be done after reading. But you're right, I should not allow another click while reading. Any advice there?

Comment: @JohnSzatmari That's really another question (maybe check out [UX.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)?). I'd say just disable the button and re-enable it when the task is finished.

Comment: @Michael I'll do just that, for now at least.

Comment: Using a background thread definitely makes sense for your use case - what I meant is creating new threads in reaction of a user input can become cumbersome (what if the user keeps clicking?), and you have the problem of concurrent execution of the `read` method (should it be allowed?) You can use an `ExecutorService` for this - most probably single-threaded, as it provides you with a managed (single) thread pool to which you can submit new `Task` on-demand. However I am not sure where the problem you report comes from - would need some further investigation (is it possible to add some logs?)

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez a Task can't be re-used

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As observed in other answers, a [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) is an implementation of [`FutureTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html). From the `Task` documentation:

> As with `FutureTask`, a `Task` is a one-shot class and cannot be reused. See `Service` for a reusable `Worker`.

So you cannot reuse a task. Second and subsequent attempts to run it will just silently fail.

You could just create a new task directly every time:

```
private Task<Void> createReadValTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() { 
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            //This functions reads from memory and writes the JSON
            readDataHI(connection,commandListHI,statusHI);
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

and then do

```
readData.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

        Thread readValThread = new Thread(createReadValTask());
        readValThread.setDaemon(true);
        readValThread.start();
    }
});
```

You could also consider using a [`Service`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html), which is designed for reuse. It basically encapsulates the "create a new task every time" functionality, but adds in a lot of useful UI callbacks. A `Service` also manages a thread pool for you (via an `Executor`), so you no longer need to worry that you may be creating too many thread. (The `Executor` can also be specified, if you want to control it.)

So, e.g.:

```
Service<Void> readValDaemon = new Service<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                //This functions reads from memory and writes the JSON
                readDataHI(connection,commandListHI,statusHI);
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

and then

```
readData.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        readValThread.restart();
    }
});
```

If the mouse is clicked while the service is already running, this will automatically cancel the already running task, and restart a new one. You could add in checks if you wanted, or bind the `disable` state of `readData` to the state of the `Service`, if you wanted.

Comment: I was using another daemon to constantly update some TextViews when the embedded device is plugged or unplugged using Platform.RunLater(), so I was able to use that to block/unblock the read button based on a global variable change when reading is completed. But using a Service could let me skip this pooling functionality, if it works.

Comment: Used your idea to implement a Service and bind the button status to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Task` is kind of the wrong tool for this. It's very purposefully only designed to run once because it's a kind of [future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). It stores the result (in your case null) as a kind of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid doing expensive operations more times than is necessary. So `Task` is best suited for situations where an expensive computation must be done *just once*, and usually you would want a result from it at some point down the line.

The [documentation for `Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) is very thorough so I would give that a read.

In your case, just use a plain `Runnable`. You can use a lambda expression:

```
readData.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event)
    {
        Thread readValThread = new Thread(() -> readDataHI(a, b, c));
        readValThread.setDaemon(true);
        readValThread.start();
    }
});
```

As an aside, creating threads manually isn't considered very good practice in modern Java. Strongly consider an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this and it works. I'll look into the ExecutorService. Then if I'm not mistaken, the Task is suited for activities that change the GUI, right? And could you tell me why my method didn't work? Isn't the Task just an object that can be passed to the Thread?

Comment: @JohnSzatmari I've updated my answer which hopefully addresses some of your questions. There's some links to some programming concepts you may wish to explore a bit more.

Comment: the advantage of using a Worker (Task or Service) over spawing a plain thread with a runnable is that all observable state of the former is guaranteed to be passed on the FX-app thread - for the latter, you'll have to handle that yourself (not rocket-science but something to remember)